# Making a datatable, maybe also with column filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables

In case the table has class `'trans'` - run `dataTable()` and `columnFilter()`; otherwise  just run `dataTable()`.

Is it possible to **not repeat** the `dataTable()` part?

```
$('#dt_a').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('trans')) {
            $(this).dataTable({
                "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'<'dt_actions'>l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                "sPaginationType": "bootstrap_alt",
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
                }
            })
            .columnFilter({
                sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
                aoColumns: [
                    null,
                    { type: "text" },
                    { type: "text" },
                    { type: "date-range" },
                    { type: "text" },
                    { type: "text" },
                    null,
                    null
                ]
            });
        } else {
            $(this).dataTable({
                "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'<'dt_actions'>l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                "sPaginationType": "bootstrap_alt",
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**NOTE:**

`columnFilter` is an extension to `dataTable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some variables. You don't need to chain function calls; it's just a neat thing you *can* do when appropriate, but it's not required.

```
$('#dt_a').each(function() {
  var target = $(this), // store this 
      table  = target.dataTable({  // and store this too
          "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'<'dt_actions'>l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
          "sPaginationType": "bootstrap_alt",
          "oLanguage": {
              "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
          }
      });

    if (target.hasClass('trans')) {
        table.columnFilter({
            sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
            aoColumns: [
                null,
                { type: "text" },
                { type: "text" },
                { type: "date-range" },
                { type: "text" },
                { type: "text" },
                null,
                null
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Neat! I didn't know chaining function calls wasn't necessary. Now I know. Cheers!

Comment: @gmaggio The reason chaining works, is that one function call returns an object, and then you call the next function in the chain on that object. So for instance `$(...)` returns an object, and you can either call something on that object directly (chaining), or you can stick that object in a variable for later use. In other words, you can always cut a chain in 2 or more pieces.